# Why is my JWT token different when I make the same http call using curl versus flutter?

Tags: http, jwt, token, amazon-cognito

I have have a c# backend with AWS Lambda. My backend has a function that authenticates users with AWS cognito and sends an IDToken response back through the response body: `return Ok(idToken);`

I am calling the exact same http request with flutter and curl, but the responses are different.

Here is the request in flutter:

```
final requestBody =
    jsonEncode({"Username": "Myusername", "Password": "Mysecretpassword"});
final request = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(
        "https://myAWSLink/signin"),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: requestBody);
```

Here is the request in curl:

```
curl -X POST "https://myAWSLink/signin" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "Username": "myusername",
  "Password": "Mysecretpassword"
}'
```

As you can see they both have the same link, headers, and body, but the response is different. The response of the curl command has 1063 characters length, but the response of my flutter application only has 1023 characters length. Because of this when I try to send the IDToken to authenticate my API it doesn't work with the Flutter response, but it does work with the curl response.

It seems as if Flutter is skipping certain characters when it receives the IDtoken. Why is this happening? How can I get the flutter response to match the response of Curl?

Comment: If you compare the tokens in the two responses, what is exactly the difference? Maybe some type of special characters are missing or is it truncated at the end etc.?

Comment: @PeterKoltai the signature is the part that is different. The signature of the Flutter request always has 303 characters, and the signature of the curl request always has 343 characters. The header and payload match the same character count and letters. It is hard to say whether it is truncated because every time you make the same call then the signature is different, but one thing for sure is the character count is always less on Flutter request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the request was actually receiving the entire 1063 character count IDToken, but the problem is I was trying to print the entire IDToken using `debugPrint(IDToken)` and the max character limit that flutter allows you to print in one statement is 1023. Since IDToken exceeds 1023 characters it was truncating anything after the 1023 limit. This is how I fixed it:

```
// print the first 200 characters of the token:
debugPrint(request.body.substring(0, 200));
// print the remaining characters
debugPrint(request.body.substring(200));
```